# How many stars will the printed from the execution of this program?

Tags: c, operating-system

This is a question for my mid-term. I know there gonna be 2 stars after running program. But I am not sure why. And this question wants me to draw a diagram to illustrate the reason. I am not sure how to draw it.

Thanks for any help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


unsigned char i;
int main() {
    unsigned int fs;
    for (i=0; i<2; i++) {
        fs = fork();
        if (fs) { printf("*\n"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read [fork()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) sys call. Check out its return value for parent and child process.

Comment: **One** question per question. You've got 2 questions with absolutely nothing connecting the 2, except that the piece of the code happens to be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System call Fork() is used to create processes.
It returns an integer which works like this:

1. If fork() returns a negative value, the creation of a child process
   was unsuccessful.
2. fork() returns a zero to the newly created child process.
3. fork() returns a positive value, the process ID of the child
   process, to the parent.

Following is the example of a process tree diagram:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
   fork(); /* A */
   ( fork()  /* B */ &&
     fork()  /* C */ ) || /* B and C are grouped according to precedence */
   fork(); /* D */
   fork(); /* E */

   printf("forked\n");
   return 0;
}
```

Diagram:
[image]

For more clear explanation go to this link :
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fork-and-binary-tree/

Comment: Thank you so much. I read your link and watch this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PwxTbksJ2fo . I kind of understand what is going on. Really helpful. One thing I still want to know what is this related to my second part of question. What .bss .data .text and .rotate going to be? Thanks!

Comment: If you can go through this link it will be very helpful: https://jvns.ca/blog/2014/09/06/how-to-read-an-executable/

Answer (score 2):

System call [fork()](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call)) is used to create processes. It takes no arguments and returns a process ID.

The purpose of fork() is to create a new process, which becomes the child process of the caller. After a new child process is created, both processes will execute the next instruction following the fork() system call.

**Return values of fork()**

If fork() returns a **negative value**, the **creation** of a child process was **unsuccessful**.

fork() returns a **zero** to the newly **created child process**.

fork() returns a **positive value**, the **process ID** of the **child** process, to the parent.

Refer : http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html